# Are there any Extended Universe references in “Star Wars Episode VII: The Force Awakens?”

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, star-wars-legends

Disney/Lucasfilm have claimed to have scrubbed the Extended Universe from future consideration in the future Disney-based *Star Wars: Episode VII - XII* movie timeline.

That said, are there any Extended Universe references that might have been snuck into “Star Wars Episode VII: The Force Awakens?”

Comment: Thanks! Both answers are great, and I'm having a tough time choosing between them. For now, I'm selecting Thunderforge's answer because of the enhanced references included.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few things from Legends that made its way into Episode VII, but there are many more elements that have an uncanny resemblance to things in Legends.

### Same as Legends

- Crossguard lightsabers [first appeared in Legends](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Crossguard_lightsaber), although with a different appearance despite the same name
- "Light" as a term for the Light Side of the Force was first used in Legends
- The word "Starkiller" has existed since George Lucas' [original draft](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Star_Wars:_Rough_Draft) of *Star Wars* and was the code name of [Galen Marek](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galen_Marek) in *The Force Unleashed*

### Seemingly inspired by Legends

*To my knowledge, there are no statements from anyone working on The Force Awakens that these were intentionally drawn from Legends, but the similarities are uncanny.*

- The general plot of the Rebellion successfully restoring the Republic and the Empire living on in different forms and under new leadership is common in Legends material, such as the Thrawn trilogy
- A villain named Ky**b**o Ren existed in *[Star Wars: Droids: The Adventures of R2-D2 and C-3PO](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Droids:_The_Adventures_of_R2-D2_and_C-3PO)*
- Kylo Ren's mask seems suspiciously similar to [Darth Revan's mask](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Revan%27s_mask), which is also worn with a black hooded cloak
- A Skywalker (Luke) had a son named [Ben](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ben_Skywalker)
- Han and Leia had a son named [Jacen](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Caedus), who trained with Luke at his newly founded Jedi Academy and later fell to the dark side, just as Ben/Kylo Ren did. Also, he killed a family member ([Mara Jade](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mara_Jade_Skywalker), Luke's wife, his aunt) to fully embrace the Dark Side

  - Note that Jacen had a twin sister, [Jaina](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jaina_Solo_Fel), and there are some theories that Rey is Ben's sister
- Luke's original lightsaber being [recovered from Cloud City and later passed on to others](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker%27s_second_lightsaber#The_Emperor.27s_trophy_.283.E2.80.939_ABY.29)

You could also argue that there were more planet-destroying weapons in Legends, but I think that Starkiller base was more likely to be inspired by the Death Star in the films than by Legends.

Other plots, like Leia having a tumultuous relationship with New Republic leadership, occurred in Legends, but seem to me like they could easily be a coincidence, whereas the things above have an uncanny resemblance.

By the way, this is not a new thing, as [all the movies have had Legends elements added to them](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Legends_elements_in_the_films) (yes, even *A New Hope* via the Special Edition).

Comment: Starkiller base reminds me a lot of the Centerpoint Station.

Comment: @Petersaber Both are reminiscent of the Death Star, so it's hard to say that Starkiller Base was inspired by Centerpoint Station. As I said, there are plenty of planet-destroying weapons in Legends, which all function like the Death Stars.

Comment: But Centerpoint Station and Starkiller Base are different from the other superweapons, and they share that difference - they shoot concentrated energy through hyperspace to points far away in the galaxy. They are both capable of destroying entire solar systems with one shot. They are both powered by a star (siphoned or artifical).

Answer (score 4):

Disney did not scrub EU from future consideration. On the contrary, they explicitly said that the Story Group and the creators have full access to it to steal ideas.

As such, there were possible references, though none of them were acknowledged:

1. Skywalker family tree:

   - Vader's grandchild called Ben (after Kenobi, presumably)

     Ben SKywalker <=> Ben Solo-or-Organa
   - Hand and Leia having a male child who turned to the Dark Side

     Jacen Solo <=> Ben Solo-or-Organa

     - And who kills a member of Skywalker family as right of Dark passage

     Mara Skywalker/Jade <=> Han Solo

     - And who ends up fighting against a female grandchild of Vader

     Jaina Solo <=> Rey (presumably! We don't know if she's Luke's daughter but it seems strongly implied)
   - Luke teaches the next Dark Jedi and joins Obi-Wan's club of awful teachers

     Kyp Durron, or some other turned-dark Jedi Academy students <=> Kylo Ren
2. Items:

   - Luke's old lightsaber from Cloud City is retrieved

     Joruus C'Baoth <=> Maz Kanata

     - And ends up being given to a Skywalker

     Luke gives it to Mara <=> Rey (assuming the film hints are not misleading and she's Luke's child).
3. Technical advances

   - Shielded TIE fighters

     TIE/advanced, TIE/defender etc... vs TIE/fo and TIE/sf
   - Kylo Ren's lightsaber

     We saw weird LS designs in EU before.
4. Other

   - Non-Sith Dark Side users

     Nightsisters and many others <=> Snoke and especially Kylo Ren
   - People hunting down Vader's stuff like it's Elvis's toothbrush.

     Glove of Darth Vader <=> Kylo Ren's Vader's helmet
   - Sienar Fleet Systems

     They are called Sienar-Jaemus Fleet Systems by the First Order time (Visual Dictionary), but they still make TIE fighters
   - The whole concept of The New Republic coexisting with Imperial Remnant
   - Leia falling out of favor with New Republic leadership over politics
   - Sun Crusher/Galaxy Gun/Centerpoint vs. Starkiller.

     Both the "new Imperial superweapon" in general, and in the latter case, "hyperspace delivery beam superweapon".
   - An ace X-Wing pilot running around having decidedly not-only-piloting adventures

     Wedge Antilles <=> Poe Dameron
   - Muun Dark Force User

     Darth Plagueis <=> Snoke (at this point, he clearly looks almost-Muun, but it's not 100% he is one, and even more unsure that he's Plagueis himself)
   - Female high level officers in Empire

     Admiral Daala <=> Captain Phasma
   - Han confronting assorted gangsters who aren't just Jabba

     Han Solo Trilogy <=> Scene where they meet Rey
   - Han running con schemes (in OT he was just a smuggler, no cons)

     Han Solo Trilogy <=> Scene where they meet Rey
   - Admiral Thrawn

     This is not exactly Episode 7 but is Disney Canon nonetheless: at the end of *Aftermath* novel, they introduced a strange admiral(ish) figure that Admiral Sloane (she of the Rebels) reported to... and he had very Admiral-Thrawn-ish vibe. We do NOT yet know if he will be featured in 7-8-9 films in any way.

Comment: I believe nightsisters are canon and not EU right?

Comment: @IvoBeckers - they were EU before they were canon. Original hipsters. :)