# Did anyone at LucasFilm acknowledge specific cases of borrowing from EU/Legends?

Tags: star-wars, canon, behind-the-scenes

- We know that Lucasfilm officially stated that [they would use Legends/EU materials as (re)sources for new Disney canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111822/976):

  > Creators of new Star Wars entertainment have full access to the rich content of the Expanded Universe. (*Official Darth Mickey <strike>Order 66</strike> New Disney Canon announcement*)
  >
  > @Hoopserwan It's all non-canon, **but it all exists as a resource that could be used down the line** (*Heddle on Twitter*).
- We know that they [likely did use EU/Legends as a resource, for The Force Awakens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112734/are-there-any-extended-universe-references-in-star-wars-episode-vii-the-force?rq=1).

  But that knowledge is basically fan deductions, not first-hand information.

As such:

### Did anyone at LucasFilm (or licensed material creators) acknowledge specific cases of borrowing specific information/ideas from EU/Legends into Disney Canon?

(as opposed to generic fact that "yes we will/do/did")

Just to clarify, the question is about canon material created after Disney transitions, NOT [Lucas's own use](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15283/did-george-lucas-use-any-of-the-expanded-universe-material-in-the-prequel-trilog/15297#15297) of EU material in Episodes I-VI or *Clone Wars*.

Comment: I think Star Wars Rebels is doing it's best to re-canonise as much of the old EU as it can. Not sure if that is the same thing as borrowing Ideas.

Comment: @JeremyFrench and damn me if I don't have a soft spot for that show simply because of that fact. Especially the ships!

Comment: @Petersaber : And Thrawn, for that matter.

Comment: @DBPriGuy and "Jan Ors" 2.0 :P

Comment: Seems a lot like this question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/99302/31051; are you asking if anybody has done this, or just if anyone's fessed up to doing it?

Comment: @JasonBaker - "fessed up" is such a crude term. But yes, the latter. I want explicit "yes, we took this from EU" acknowledgement.

Answer (score 5):

### Yeah, there's been some of this

[Grand Admiral Thrawn](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mitth%27raw%27nuruodo) is, of course, the obvious example; his history in the Expanded Universe was discussed by Dave Filoni at Celebration London 2016, as [reported by](http://ew.com/article/2016/07/16/star-wars-rebels-resurrects-grand-admiral-thrawn/) *Entertainment Weekly*:

> "Let's take a moment and expand the universe a little," Filoni said as the lights dimmed and the [[*Rebels* season 3](https://youtu.be/xmXp802sFgQ)] trailer began to play. (You can see it yourself above.)
>
> *[...]*
>
> "You couldn't have grown up a Star Wars fan without encountering Thrawn in *Heir to the Empire*," Filoni said. "It was a dark time when there weren't any more movies, and it blew our minds that there could be more."

Pablo Hidalgo, one of Lucasfilm's story development executive, has been known to do this on occasion on [his Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo); there's [a great example](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/730589067386204161) from May 2016 where he makes an (admittedly non-specific) admission that he and Dave Filoni, among others, tend to borrow from the EU:

[image]

> **@BLloydReese** there was a TON of stuff from EU  filoni stuck in.
>
> **@pablohidalgo** Yeah, the EU stuff primarily came from EU readers like Filoni or myself.

One example, from the *Rogue One Visual Guide* (written by Hidalgo) are the Yelsain Tree Dwellers; the planet [Yelsain](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yelsain/Legends), with its giant trees, was entirely unremarkable in the EU. However, Hidalgo apparently made great use of it back when he was running tabletop *Star Wars* RPGs, so [added it](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/819396774645276672) to Disney canon with an updated history out of a sense of sentimentality:

[image]

> **@pablohidalgo** In my old campaigns, I blew out the history of the Yelsain Tree Dwellers. Couldn't resist bringing 'em back.

Comment: wouldn't call it a dark time when there were no more movies. the opposite actually.